# Grouping by Month in SQL Error

Tags: sql, group-by

I'm using the following code;

```
SELECT 
    SUM(PlanTotal) as PlanTotal, PlanStartDate
FROM 
    TEST.dbo.Plans
WHERE  
    DATEDIFF(MONTH, cast(cast(PlanStartDate AS varchar(8)) AS datetime), GETDATE()) <= 6
GROUP BY 
    PlanStartDate
ORDER BY 
    PlanStartDate
```

This brings me back the plan total for each day of `PlanStartDate` in the last six months however I am trying to find the Plan Total for each month. I thought if I did something like this it would work;

```
SELECT 
   SUM(PlanTotal) as PlanTotal, MONTH(PlanStartDate)
FROM 
   TEST.dbo.Plans
WHERE  
   DATEDIFF(MONTH, CAST(CAST(PlanStartDate AS varchar(8)) AS datetime), GETDATE()) <= 6
GROUP BY 
   MONTH(PlanStartDate)
```

However I just get an error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I need to include the cast function as `PlanStartDate` is in numeric function not `datetime`.

Thanks

Comment: What is the datatype for PlanStartDate? ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you have is due to conversion from a string to a date.  This would only occur in your query if `PlanStartDate` were a string.

Because your original query works, I suspect this will work as well:

```
SELECT SUM(PlanTotal) as PlanTotal, MONTH(cast(cast(PlanStartDate as varchar(8)) as datetime))
FROM TEST.dbo.Plans
WHERE  DATEDIFF(MONTH, cast(cast(PlanStartDate as varchar(8)) as datetime), GETDATE()) <= 6
GROUP BY MONTH(cast(cast(PlanStartDate as varchar(8)) as datetime));
```

To avoid such problems, you should store dates as, well, dates and not strings or numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be reproduced quite simply with:

```
SELECT  MONTH(20140624) -- TODAY'S DATE AS AN INT
```

To get around this I would store dates in a valid format, but failing this you can extract the month using the following:

```
SELECT  FLOOR(20140617 % 1000 / 100)
```

Your predicate is also not [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable), any index you might have on PlanStartDate is useless after you have converted the value twice, then put it inside DATEDIFF. You could rewrite your predicate as follows to allow the use of an index:

```
WHERE   PlanStartDate >= CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE()), 112) + '01')
AND     PlanStartdate <= GETDATE();
```

The key part being you get the first date that would give a `DATEDIFF` of less than or equal to 6, and select all records with a later date (less than today). Since `GETDATE()` is only evaluated once at the start of the query the following part is evaluated once, and doesn't need to be reevaluated for every row:

```
CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE()), 112) + '01')
```

Giving a final query of:

```
SELECT  SUM(PlanTotal) as PlanTotal, FLOOR(20140617 % 1000 / 100) AS Month
FROM    TEST.dbo.Plans
WHERE   PlanStartDate >= CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE()), 112) + '01')
AND     PlanStartdate <= GETDATE()
GROUP BY FLOOR(20140617 % 1000 / 100);
```

This has removed all conversions on your data, so will optimise much better. I'd still be inclined to just bite the bullet though and convert PlanStartDate to a DATE if I were you though.